# Error with two process access to critical section

Tags: c++, c, fork

Some one can informe me how to solve this compile error :

```
tarek.c: In function ‘main’:
tarek.c:33: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
/tmp/ccAEGS6k.o: In function `main':
tarek.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
tarek.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

when i compile this program (Two process shared the same value using critical section) :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {

int stat;

pthread_mutex_t *mutex = (pthread_mutex_t*)mmap (0, sizeof (pthread_mutex_t) + sizeof (long),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                            MAP_SHARED ,-1, 0);

long *data = (long*)(&mutex[1]); /* map 'data' after mutex */
int pid;

pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
pthread_mutexattr_init (&attr);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared (&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_mutex_init (mutex, &attr);

*data = 0;

pid = fork ();

pthread_mutex_lock (mutex);
(*data)++;
pthread_mutex_unlock (mutex);

if (!pid) /* child exits */
exit (0);
else
waitpid (pid, &stat, 0);
printf ("data is %ld\n", *data);

}
```

Comment: Do you mean `How to solve compile error`?. This is not problem related `two process`. You don't specify library to compiler. for example `-lpthread` ?

Comment: you mean gcc myprogram.c -lpthread ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly mention `-pthread` library .

Do compilation like this:

```
gcc -Wall program.c -o program -pthread
```

It will solve your

```
`tarek.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
tarek.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared'`
```

For `exit()` include `#include <stdlib.h>`

For `waitpid()` include `#include <sys/wait.h>`

for more [man exit()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit)  and [man waitpid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)

Comment: I have this error know :
`program.c: In function ‘main’:
program.c:33: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’
program.c:33: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
program.c:35: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘waitpid’
program.c:38: warning: control reaches end of non-void function`

Comment: for warning message : I must say that you are not returning `int ` from `main` so put one last line `return 0` in `main()`.. and also it solved your few problems regarding `tarek.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init' `and all so for exit let me look into it

Comment: @Mehdi :see my edit now .. I hope you are looking for that one

Comment: after adding `return 0;` and compiling using `gcc -Wall program.c -o program -pthread` i have also this error :

`program.c: In function ‘main’:
program.c:33: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’
program.c:33: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
program.c:35: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘waitpid’`

Comment: thanks about your reply : i have just a last one 
`program.c:36: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘waitpid’
`

Comment: But after compiling, i have another error of segmentation. if you have an idea is good or i must to ask another question !

Comment: @Mehdi : Have you written this code by yourself or got it from somewhere, I gave you the idea to remove compilation error and that was your question too. But I think you should look into the code , use  `gdb` or `valgrind` kind of tool to resolve it. if not found success then ask another question, but better to understand concepts before. directly asking the question on SO won't help you much if you are a beginner get a good book and understand these things

Comment: thanks about your reply, i understand this program, i just shared a variale `data` between two process ! but i donèt know why i have this error. any way thanks for you :)

Answer (score 1):

when you build add `-lpthread` in your link command

```
gcc -o program program.c -lpthread
```

Comment: When i make `gcc program.c -lpthread`, i have this error :
program.c: In function ‘main’:
program.c:33: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’

Comment: @mehdi it's warning. So, executable are exists. if you want to remove warnings, probably, it will be fixed with `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the `exit()` error you need to `#include <stdlib.h>`